# Is it he or him that is the correct sentence?

Tags: grammar

His parents didn't want **him** to go. This is how I would write it, but when trying to translate it (to swedish) it seems **he** would be the correct word to use. I would never have thought twice about using him if it wasn't for the fact I have to explain why **him** not **he**. Please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

> *His parents didn't want him* /* *he to go*.

"He" is impossible her. The pronoun is the syntactic object of the verb "want", and hence takes accusative case "him".

The pronoun is also the *understood* subject of the subordinate clause "to go", and pronoun subjects of infinitival clauses always take accusative form.

Answer (score 0):

> His parents didn't want him to go.

This sentence is correct. "**him**" in this sentence is the object.

If you use "**he**", it will be incorrect since the word "he" must only be used as the subject of a sentence.
Let me give you some examples that are similar to this.

> Her parents didn't want her to go.
>
> My parents didn't want me to go.
>
> Our parents didn't want us to go.
>
> Their parents didn't want them to go.
>
> Your parents didn't want you to go.

Therefore, the translation that you translate that sentence in English into Swedish might be wrong.

Comment: As I thought, but great with some clarifications!!